# How to read excel workbooks with varying sheet names in parallel?

Tags: r, file, parallel-processing, xlsx

I am trying to use `parLapplyLB` to read excel files

```
file.list <- list.files(path="folder path", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)

test <- parLapplyLB(cl, file.list, function(x){
    readxl::read_excel(x, sheet=sheet_in_file)
    }
```

My problem is that each file in file.list has a different "sheet" name that I need to read. For e.g. in file1, I need to read sheet = "abc", in file2, need to read sheet = "xyz" etc.
I tried few things but I have not been able to achieve this, is there a way to do it using `parLapplyLB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parLapplyLB` as parallelized variant of `lapply` essentially loops over one list. What you want is a multivariate variant which allows you to loop over the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. element in both of your two lists, where the single-threaded version would be `Map` (with a big M). The parallelized version `mcMap` lives in the `parallel` package you are using as well.

We may use `parallel::mcMap`.

```
library(parallel)
r <- mcMap(openxlsx::read.xlsx, file.list, sheet_in_file)
r
# r$`./foo/wb1.xlsx`
# X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  1
# 
# $`./foo/wb2.xlsx`
# X1 X2 X3
# 1  2  2  2
# 2  2  2  2
# 
# $`./foo/wb3.xlsx`
# X1 X2 X3
# 1  3  3  3
# 2  3  3  3
# 
# $`./foo/wb4.xlsx`
# X1 X2 X3
# 1  4  4  4
# 2  4  4  4
```

(Should work similarly with `readxl::read_excel`, don't have it installed on this machine.)

Also see *@HenrikB*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998919/r-reading-excel-workbooks-using-parallel/72998981?noredirect=1#comment128943171_72998981) below for a solution using a different package.

---

*Data:*

```
dir.create('foo')  ## create dir
## create four lists of four dataframes, write to dir as .xlsx
lapply(1:4, \(j) openxlsx::write.xlsx(lapply(1:4, \(i) data.frame(matrix(i, 2, 3))) |> setNames(LETTERS[1:4]), 
                                      file=sprintf('./foo/wb%s.xlsx', j), overwrite=TRUE)) |>invisible()

file.list <- list.files(path = "./foo", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)

sheet_in_file <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Comment: FYI, "parallelMap is considered retired from the mlr-org team. We won’t add new features anymore and will only fix severe bugs. We suggest to use other parallelization frameworks such as the future package. The new mlr3 framework also relies on the future package for parallelization and not on parallelMap anymore as mlr did." [https://parallelmap.mlr-org.com/]

Comment: In the same vein as what jay.sf suggests, use a map-reduce function that can iterate over multiple arguments.  The go-to sequential solution in base-R is `mapply()`, e.g. `y <- mapply(readxl::read_excel, file.list, sheet_in_file)`. After you made sure to get that one correct, switch to the parallel version in **future.apply** package, e.g. `y <- future_mapply(readxl::read_excel, file.list, sheet_in_file)`.  If you like **purrr**, then you can use its `map2()` for sequential processing and `furrr::future_map2()` for the parallel versions.